# Python Convert Letters Numbers

Tags: string, python-3.x

can somebody help me figure out how to convert a string to a number? Let's say a user inputs "1-800-Flowers" I want python to display "1-800-3569377"

All I have so far is:

```
userInput = input("Please enter a phone number (e.g. 1-800-Flowers): ")
phoneNum = userInput.replace('-','')
```

That's really all I have. Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`str.translate`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate):

```
>>> pad = ['qz', 'abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl', 'mno', 'prs', 'tuv', 'wxy']
>>> letter_to_numbers = {
...     ord(ch): ord(str(i))
...     for i, chs in enumerate(pad, 1)
...     for ch in chs
... } # Map ord('f') to ord('3'), ...
>>> "1-800-Flowers".lower().translate(letter_to_numbers)
'1-800-3569377'
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a for loop that loops through the string inputted by the user and then for every letter or number, convert it into its ASCII value using the ord() function.

```
other=[]
userInput = input("Please enter a phone number (e.g. 1-800-Flowers): ")
for i in userInput:
 other+=[ord(i)]

print(other)
```

What you were saying didn't make sense to me though, as `"1-800-Flowers"` does not equate to `"1-800-3569377"` if you convert it to ASCII, you can even check for yourself at the [ASCII converter site](http://www.branah.com/ascii-converter). Do correct me if what I saying is wrong however.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I do it with a more straightforward translate:

```
letters       = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
letter_digits = "22233344455566677778889999"
letter_to_digit = string.maketrans(letters+letters.lower(),letter_digits+letter_digits)

# convert letters to digits
new_phone = raw_phone.translate(letter_to_digit)
```